# How much juice is in 1 pear

Tags: fruit

For a science project I need to know how much juice is in 1 pear or apple.
I looked on the internet, but didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: This will vary by the type of pear or apple, its size and the method of juicing. Try searching home winemaking and homebrew sites. I found some links that seem to indicate it is about 10 lbs of pears/apples for 3-4 quarts of juice, but some say 20 lbs. It depends on the fruit. But honestly, you should probably test it yourself with several.

Comment: If it's for a science project, isn't it maybe the point to measure it? I'm sure someone can answer this (at least with a rough range) but just being told the answer might not actually be what you need for your project.

Comment: You might want to clarify: water content (see below) or amount of juice that can be pressed out (experiment yourself)?

Answer (score 1):

Study linked below states that pears are made up of 84% water. So 84% of the weight of the pear in grams would be a close estimate to the weight of water of the pear, in grams. Water weighs 1 ml per gram, so you could then convert the weight in grams of the water to ml of water in the pear.

[Water Content of Fruits and Vegetables](https://www2.ca.uky.edu/enri/pubs/enri129.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is "juice yield", and lo and behold tables can be found:

http://juicernet.com/average-juice-yields-fruits-vegetables/